# How to Filter data using combobox in VB.Net using msql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, phpmyadmin

im trying to filter a data in my Gridviews, but the data does not appear, can you help?
This is the code:

```
Sub launchLapangan()
    Call Connection()
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    Cmd = New OdbcCommand("Select * from lapangan", Conn)
    Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While Rd.Read
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Rd.Item(0))
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Call Connection()
    '(This for choose the filter from table lapangan)'
    Cmd = New OdbcCommand("Select * from lapangan where id_lapangan ='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", Conn)
    Rd = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    Rd.Read()
    If Rd.HasRows Then
        LabelHarga.Text = Rd!harga_lapangan
        LabelJenis.Text = Rd!jenis_rumput
        LabelDP.Text = Rd!DP  

        '(This the error/data doesnt appear)'
        '(then i will show the filter using foreign key id_lapangan which exist in table detail_reservasi)'
        Da = New OdbcDataAdapter("Select * from detail_reservasi", Conn)
        Ds = New DataSet
        Da.Fill(Ds, "detail_reservasi")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables("detail_reservasi")
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Can you Help Me?
im using Mysql database in XAMPP

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You've already got all the data from the `lapangan` table in the `ComboBox` so why would you be querying that same table again when the user selects an item? The whole point is that you are supposed to be querying a different table using that selection as a filter but, when you query the `detail_reservasi` table, there is no `WHERE` clause so there is no filter.

Comment: ohh i got it sir, the problem is resolved, I chose the wrong data before :D